# NO lock in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am building a desktop application with back-end in MySQL.
Does Mysql Support No Lock or some thing equivalent to this as in sql?

```
Select * from Tablename (NoLock);
```

Suppose I am fetching data from multiple tables using join, Then do i Need to implement this code while selecting rows from each and every  table?

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
SELECT * FROM 'Table1' 
 iNNERjOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.FK=TABLE1.PK ;
COMMIT ;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
SELECT * FROM Tablename ;
COMMIT ;
```

Comment: is it single statement works on multiple tables if i use joins

Comment: in my knowledge it will work.But i am not sure on that

Comment: It will work for many tables and joins. Actually it will ignore all locks until you revert it using: `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the isolation level in the mysql config file to avoid having to call SET TRANSACTION for every query:

[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED